# Light from oscillating electric and magnetic fields

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, optics, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

Here’s a pretty weird question:

Is it possible to create light out of oscillating electric and magnetic fields?
That is if I oscillate an electric field in a direction that is orthogonal to the oscillating magnetic field, will this create light?

---

This question is purely theoretical and hypothetical. An answer may or may not exist. But I just wanted to know whether this is even possible with our current physics or maybe physics doesn’t allow this to happen at all. I do not know what the setup would be for this assuming it’s possible.

Comment: Light *is* oscillating electrical and magnetic fields. You can not create it *without* generating oscillating electrical and magnetic fields.

Comment: But you would find it difficult to generate an electrical signal to drive a conventional antenna at the required frequencies in the 100's of THz.

Comment: @ThePhoton exactly i would need a oscillating electric and magnetic field. But as I said I don’t know the setup to create this. This is purely hypothetical.

Comment: The usual way is to excite some charged particle into a state where it will tend to relax into a lower energy state while exciting the EM field.

Comment: @ThePhoton true. But that’s the conventional way to create light. Like heating up of a tungsten filament in a light bulb. I wasn’t thinking about that. What is wish is to first create a electric field which will oscillate. Then create a magnetic field which will oscillate. And then orient both perpendicular to each other. I know this makes no sense. Hence the note at the end of the question. Thanks.

Comment: Maxwell's equations make it "difficult" to create an oscillating electric field that doesn't itself produce a perpendicular oscillating magnetic field.

Comment: @ThePhoton so does that mean that if I create an oscillating electric field, I will invariably create light because oscillating electric fields also generate oscillating magnetic fields?

Comment: yes, the equations   say so, oscilating electric fields create oscillating magnetic fields an vice verso,  no exception. this is always validated by data. In antennas one oscillates electric field,(magnetic fields are harder) and the electromagnetic wave leaves the antenna

Comment: If you "create" an oscillating electric field, then Maxwell's equations tells you that this coexists with an oscillating magnetic field. They are not separate things.

Comment: Is your question specifically about (visible) light, rather than EM radiation in general? You probably know that radio waves and microwaves are created essentially in a rod antenna by creating an oscillating electric field and an oscillating magnetic field (induced by the electrons moving back and forth between the ends of the rod). But for visible light, you'd need a very high frequency, and you couldn't build an antenna that creates such a high-frequency field.

Comment: @StephanMatthiesen no just EM waves in general.

Comment: @annav, a loop antenna isn't very hard to make (for appropriate frequencies).

Comment: @ThePhoton , well as there are no magnetic monopoles the signal is higher order in magnetic changes, no? and therefore weaker?

Answer (score 1):

I think there should be an interplay between E and B field's changes in space and time. There should be a correlation between this two. The factor is not only the oscillating field but their variation (just like any normal wave equation). As you see that the potentials $\phi$ and $\bar{A}$ are just time and space component of four vector, $A^{\mu}$. So these E and B fields are the just different reflection of same four vector or same physics (Electromagnetism).

Answer (score 1):

> That is if I oscillate an electric field in a direction that is orthogonal to the oscillating magnetic field, will this create light?

How a time varying electric or a magnetic field should be created?

1. This is possible by a redistribution of charges ( applying an external electric field). The best example will be the oscillation of electrons in an antenna rod or any wire. As a result of the accelerated electrons they emit photons.
2. Applying an external magnetic field, the involved subatomic particles get aligned with their magnetic dipole moments. During the relaxation they emit EM radiation too.
3. Running electrons in curved paths - for example applying a magnetic field non parallel to the direction of movement, electrons will loose their kinetic energy, emit light and came to a standstill.

So however you induce an oscillating electric or magnetic field, you will influence some subatomic particles of an influenced body and follow one of the above scenarios. Or could one give different examples? The emission of light aka EM radiation is always the result of manipulation of subatomic particles. No radiation without materialistic sources.